# Get All Indexes with names , types, properties in Mongo java

Tags: mongodb, morphia, mongo-java-driver

I want to retrieve all the indexes from Mongo using java. I am using Morphia but am open to using Mongo-Java-Driver as well. I would like to list and iterate over all the indexes , as well as get their types, properties, names. How can I do so?

I tried the following :

```
  MongoCollection mongoCollection = client.getDatabase("mofinance").getCollection("FinanceDetails");
            mongoCollection.listIndexes();
```

But this gives me LinkedHashMap object which contains key and value pairs and  I have to iterate using custom recursive code. I want something like index.getName(), index.unique(), index.sparse..

Any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method in Morphia or the Java driver.  You'll have to write the code and iterate over the collection names doing what you have above.

Comment: Ya @evanchooly I parsed the response and stored it in a custom class , only then was I able to parse it,